# Smarty templates: Is it possible to extend basic {block} to add custom functionality?

Tags: php, smarty, template-engine, smarty3

I have very specific task with templates. I need to extend standard Smarty 3 ( 3.1-DEV ) template system to get custom {block} functions, but keep basic features ( adding/rewrite, summing, etc. )
Generally I need to handle each {block} contend to get next functionality:

- ignore content of each single template which are outside of {block} (
  template source does not matter )
- keep a "references" to the processed {block} content ( I want to get cached content of any block which was "displayed" in smarty destructor, but don't want to keep it in memory )
- got same inheritance features ( be able to get nested block parents, etc. )
- preserve native smarty caching system
- and don't modify smarty engine directly, implement via plugins and class extending

I have tried to create custom block function, but it loosing inheritance features on native {block} and I can't control displayed/processed content and get it content in destructor.

Main idea is to process all `$smarty->display()` and `$smarty->fetch()` calls, collect content of all blocks and keep references to their content, but not display immediately.

Content must be displayed in main smarty instance destructor. Content for display must be assembled using processed blocks.

Probably there are some other templating solution for this task, or there are any ready-to-use features in smarty, but I can't find it.
I aslo don't want to change smarty template system and refuse to use php-templating `<? if( $a < $b ): ?> <b>Output</b> <? endif; ?>` it's too ugly for me.

**upd**: I want to implement "two step view" with Smarty, but make it easy and simple.

Thanks.